# How do I take the implicit partial derivative when the variable is not equal to the equation?

Tags: partial-derivative, implicit-differentiation

So my homework problem is as follows:
$$
\text{Consider the equation }xz^2-6yz+4log(z)=-1 \text{ as defining }z\text{ implicitly as a function of } x \text{ and } y \text{.}\\
\text{The values of } \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \text{ and } \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} \text{ at } (5,1,1) \text{ are _____ and _____. }\\
\text{Remember, in webwork "log" means the natural logarithm.}
$$

All the examples I've seen where we take the partial derivative and assume a variable is a function of the other variables, we have the whole equation equal to that variable. (eg $z = f(x, y) = x^2 + 7xy + 1$ or something else, this is an arbitrary example).

I thought that maybe I need to solve for $z$ first, and then I could take the implicit partial at that point. I couldn't see any obvious way to solve for $z$ algebraically, so I figured the quadratic equation was the route to go and started writing out:

$$
z = \frac{-6y \pm \sqrt((-6y)^2-4(x)(\text{(how do I get }c\text{ from }4log(z)\text{ here?}))}{(2x)}
$$

So I'm thinking that overall, there's probably a simple rule or solution that I'm overlooking which is leading me on a wild goosechase.

What is the correct first step I need to take so I can perform the partial derivative?

EDIT:
The comment from GFauxPas made me think that perhaps all I needed to do was use prime notation instead, but I'm still stuck.

$$
\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = z^2+2xzz'-6yz'+\frac{4z'}{z} = 0 \\
\text{Solving for }z'\text{ gave me}\\
z'=\frac{z^3}{2xz^2-6yz+4} = \frac{1}{8}
$$
When we plugin 5,1,1 that is, but that isn't showing as the correct answer. Am I at least on the right track?

EDIT:
I missed a negative. This is the correct answer:
$$
\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}} = - \frac{1}{8}
$$

Comment: Have you tried differentiating both sides as is?

Comment: What would I do with $z$ if I tried that? ... Wait, I think I see what to do.... Let me give it a try.

Comment: The process is similar to implicit differentiation in two variables. Remember that $y$ behaves like a constant when differentiating with respect to $x$.

Comment: @GFauxPas, I figured it out. You can just use prime notation. Thank you

Comment: You are on the right track. Avoid referring to $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ as $z'$ to avoid confusion. There may be a sign error in the calculation shown.

Comment: @OnceUponACrinoid Thanks for that tip! I was actually aware of that but what I actually needed to notice was that you can just use prime notation and then solve for $z'$.

Comment: @OnceUponACrinoid Wait, I just saw your most recent comment. If $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = z'$ then how did I get the correct answer? I took the equation with prime notation = 0, and solved for $z'$

Comment: @OnceUponACrinoid WAIT I see. Once I solve for $z'$, then it's kinda obvious that $z' = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$. Okay. I understand now. Thanks, that tip was pretty insightful.

Comment: @BCqrstoO Both operations are the same in terms of the algebra involved. But the notation is preferred because "prime" usually refers to ordinary derivatives where the variable is obvious from context.

Comment: Thanks belong to both of you, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use $prime\text{ }notation$.

First we find $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = z^2+2xzz'-6yz' + \frac{4z'}{z} = 0 \\
2xzz'-6yz' + \frac{4z'}{z} = -z^2 \\
\text{(multiply each term by }z\text{)}\\
2xz^2z' -6yzz' + 4z'= -z^3\\
\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = z' = \frac{-z^3}{2xz^2-6yz+4}
\end{align}
$$

Then we find $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = 2xzz'-6z-6yz'+\frac{4z'}{z} = 0 \\
2xzz'-6yz'+\frac{4z'}{z} = 6z \\
\text{(multiply each term by }z\text{, again)}\\
2xz^2z'-6yzz' +4z' = 6z^2 \\
\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = z' = \frac{6z^2}{2xz^2-6yz+4}
\end{align}
$$

When we plug in our point $(5, 1, 1)$ we get the answer
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{-1}{8} \text{ and }
\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = \frac{3}{4}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

What you have to use is simply the total derivative and partial differentitation.

You have $$F=f(x,y,z)=0$$ The total derivative is $$dF=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\,dx+\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\,dy+\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\,dz=F'_x\,dx+F'_y\,dy+F'_z\,dz=0$$ from which, as usual $$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=-\frac {F'_x}{F'_z}$$ $$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=-\frac {F'_y}{F'_z}$$

In your case $$F=xz^2-6yz+4\log(z)+1=0$$ then $F'_x=z^2$, $F'_y=-6z$, $F'_z=2xz-6y+\frac 4z$. So, after simplifications, $$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{z^3}{-2 x z^2+6 y z-4} $$  $$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=\frac{3 z^2}{x z^2-3 y z+2}$$

So, for the point  $(5, 1, 1)$ we obtain
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = -\frac{1}{8} ~~~~~~~~~~~~
\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = \frac{3}{4}
\end{align}
$$